# extJS comboBox. Dynamic data load

Tags: javascript, extjs, combobox

I wrote the following implementation of combo box with dynamic data upload.

**Code**

```
Loyalty.tools.DictionaryComboBox = Ext.extend(Ext.form.ComboBox,

 {
    defaultConfig:{

        defaults:{
            labelWidth:150
        },
        displayField:'value',
        valueField:'key',
        forceSelection:true,
        mode:'local',
        typeAhead: true,
        triggerAction: 'all',
        selectOnFocus:true
    },

    constructor:function (config) {
        Ext.apply(config, this.defaultConfig);
        config['store'] = new Ext.data.Store({
            fields:['key', 'value', 'description'],
            proxy:{
                type:'ajax',
                url:config.dictionaryPath + '/' + config.dictionaryName
            }
        });
        Loyalty.tools.DictionaryComboBox.superclass.constructor.call(this, config);
    }

}

 );
```

and I use it the following way

```
            new Loyalty.tools.DictionaryComboBox({
                fieldLabel: Loyalty.messages['company.grid.filter.forma'],
                dictionaryPath: config.dictionaryPath,
                dictionaryName: 'forma',
                name: 'forma',
                id:'forma',
                allowBlank:true,
                labelWidth:config.labelWidth
            }),
```

I have the two problems
1) How can I get the list data when combo box is loading( rather than on the first click)
2) and if I'm putting a key in the combo box so that it immediately display the desired value?

Answer (score 1):

1) how are you loading the store. I think you need to add autoLoad: true like so

```
fields:['key', 'value', 'description'],
autoLoad: true,
```

2) are you asking how do i select the combo box

```
var mycombo = Ext.getCmp('mycombo');
mycombo.setValue(id);
```

Comment: neither one nor the other did not work ....
1) The list is really loaded at the beginning, but then is duplicateloading when you click on it

2) does not bear a more accurate value is set, but not displayed.

I think all of this as something to do with the fact that the first load, as if ignored

Comment: try  queryMode : 'local' instead of mode : 'local'

Comment: Hi. i decided my problem. Unfortunately I had to use not "right" metod

Answer (score 1):

i decided my problem. Unfortunately I had to use not "right" metod

```
Loyalty.tools.DictionaryComboBox = Ext.extend(Ext.form.ComboBox,
    {
        defaultConfig:{

            defaults:{
                labelWidth:150
            },
            displayField:'value',
            valueField:'key',
            forceSelection:true,
            queryMode: 'local',
            typeAhead: true,
            triggerAction: 'all',
            selectOnFocus:true
        },

        constructor:function (config) {
            Ext.apply(config, this.defaultConfig);
            var isStoreProvided = (config['store'] == undefined);
            if (isStoreProvided) {
                var el = this;


   config['store'] = new Ext.data.Store({
                fields:['key', 'value', 'description'],
                autoLoad:true,
                proxy:{
                    type:'ajax',
                    url:config.dictionaryPath + '/' + config.dictionaryName
                },
                listeners: {
                    'load': function() {
                        if (config['initialValue'] != undefined) {
                            el.setValue(config['initialValue']);
                            config['initialValue'] = undefined;
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        Loyalty.tools.DictionaryComboBox.superclass.constructor.call(this, config);
    }

}
```

);